# VB.NET page with two autopostback dropdownlists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have simple VB.NET that contains two database driven dropdownlists. Each dropdownlist has an autopostback property that will execute a function that takes user to another page.

The problem I have is that if user selects dropdownlist A, is taken to the A page, but then presses back button and selects dropdownlist B, the autopostback will occur for dropdownlist A since dropdownlist A is still selected. Any ideas on how to get around this?

I've tried everything I can think of. I do reset the dropdownlist and comment out the Response.Redirect code to prove that it does actually reset. But then as soon as I put the redirect back in, it loses the reset to unselected ability. I've seen this "bug" posted elsewhere online, but have not found a solution that works.

```
Protected Sub ddlSearchAward_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlSearchAward.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim strParam As String
    strParam = ddlSearchAward.SelectedItem.Value


    Response.Redirect("awards_?criteria=" & strParam)
End Sub


Protected Sub ddlAwardList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlAwardList.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim strParam As String
    strParam = ddlAwardList.SelectedItem.Value


    Response.Redirect("awards_?id=" & strParam)

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try setting a focus on some other element before the redirection?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. I do reset the dropdownlist and comment out the Response.Redirect code to prove that it does actually reset. But then as soon as I put the redirect back in, it loses the reset to unselected ability. I've seen this "bug" posted elsewhere online, but have not found a solution that works.

Comment: I had to forgo the autopostback and put a button next to each dropdownlist to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to forgo the autopostback and put a button next to each dropdownlist to get it to work.